# Development Environment for university Linux and C course

Tags: c, environment

I'm taking my university's trial by fire C course and I need some help with the environment I'm programming in.

So, all assignments have to be uploaded to a linux remote server. All the tests suites they provide are run on this sever, using that servers specific compiler settings. (Which is why I'm really worried about just using an IDE, finishing the project, and then uploading the files to the server. I'm scared the compiler settings will be different and everything will just stop working when moved into a different environment).

Since coding on a remote at the same time as 1000 other students results in lag and crashes that makes the already unintuitive and painful experience of using VIM in a puTTy window even worse is an unbearable experience, what are my options?

Has anyone got some advice on what would be the best option for me in this situation?

Comment: Set up a git repo to share the code between your local env and the shared env, develop locally but test on the shared environment at least once a day?

Comment: 1. stop using that windows. Or use the linux subsystem of Windows 10 2.write code locally, use `git`, then push to the server using the ssh connection that you already have. Or use plain `rsync`. Or `scp`. Many IDEs such as Jetbrain's have an option to deploy code using SFTP to a remote server, but such feature might require a paid version.

Comment: Develop locally some tests if you cannot get the remote tests and once a day upload remotely and test the official tests.

Comment: Visual Study Code is reasonably friendly and provides a very nifty remote working mode (it actually spawns a headless copy of itself on remote host/WSL compartment/container).